# how to empty input field after start typing

Tags: javascript, mootools, textinput, onkeyup

I am trying to make an input box where the input box gets empty once you start typing. (Not on focus). I tried using keyup event on mootools, but the flow is not seamless. it takes some time to erase the input field. here is the code

```
document.addEvent('domready', function(e) {
$('inputBox').addEvent('keyup', function() {
    if(inputBox.value != inputBox.defaultValue){
        inputBox.value = '';
        $('inputBox').removeEvents('keyup');    
    }
});
});
```

What is best way to do it such that it can behave better?

Comment: https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mooPlaceholder- modern html5 browsers have `placeholder=` attribute. this plugin i wrote enhances ones that don't and makes this a feature for every browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Remon said, you can bind to a keydown event and you will not have any delay but then you can't do a comparison with the default value as when the key is pressed down, the value will be as same (the value changed once you get the key up).

This will be the code with keydown:

```
document.addEvent('domready', function(e) {
    $('inputBox').addEvent('keydown', function() {
        this.set('value', '').removeEvents('keydown');
    });
});
```

If you want to do a comparison as you did in your initial code, then you will need to use keyup but it will have a small delay.

Here is your code a bit optimized and working:

```
document.addEvent('domready', function(e) {
    $('inputBox').addEvent('keyup', function(ev) {
        if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
            this.set('value', ev.key).removeEvents('keyup');
        }
    });
});​
```

I hope this answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

The keyup event is triggered last of all the key events, so you might be better off binding to the keydown event, which will make your flow feel more seamless.